# How to load a scene async so you can have a loading screen?

Tags: sprite-kit

My scene loads can take a while, and I want to be able to show a loading animation, however, everything locks up. Is there a way to load the next scene async and get a callback when its ready?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can schedule a block for concurrent execution using [dispatch_async](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async). Load scene in async block then perform callback method on the main thread like this:

```
__weak MyClass *weakself = self; 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background thread
    //Load scene here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Main thread
        //Call your callback method here
        [weakself sceneLoaded:loadedScene];
    });
});
```

Comment: SpriteKit will handle all this gracefully on its own? Do I need to create a separate view for the 'Loading Scene' to play in, or can I safely share the same view?

Comment: You know that amazingly worked... I figured there would be some sort of deadlocking issues but there wasn't...Apple did a great job with SpriteKit. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I was too drunk yesterday to respond. Glad to hear it worked out neatly :)

Comment: Will referencing 'self' inside of the block create a retain cycle?  Might need to create a weak reference for use in block, e.g if your scene is called MyScene then, __weak MyScene *weakself = self; prior to the dispatch_async and use [weakself sceneLoaded:LoadedScene] instead;

Comment: @DerekH you are totally correct. It is far safer to use weak self. I updated my answer.

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir Can you please give me an example how to use the above sample code, if I am in "SplashScene" and wants to Load "MainScene" using the above code? Thanks